# Python- Mainloop Não funciona

Tags: python

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou iniciando agora e ja apanhando kkk,
A situação é a seguinte:
Estou fazendo uma telinha simples, mas a função mainloop não funciona.
Caso eu use o terminal e use class cria os "..." para a identação...
Mas quando faço a função mainloop para executar não executa, acredito ter que sair dessa identação mas ocmo faço.
Caso eu use o tkinter o acione o F5, ele gera uma mensagem invalid sintaxe e
coloca o foco no número 6 da versão do python.
abaixo imagens:  [image: Terminal]

[image: Tkinter]

Comment: Faltam os dois pontos e identação, `def __init__(...):`

Comment: Ola Miguel, quando eu coloco os dois pontos ali onde vc falou, ta invalid sintaxe.

Comment: oi Jonga - o seu problema é fácil resolver, mas você está misturando muito as coisas ainda - sem entender bem o que é mensagem do sistema, oq ue é da linguagem,   que está dentro de um bloco, etc.... eu sugiro pegar uma documentação ou tutorial mais básico, e depois voltar aí. De umaolahda nos links aqui: https://wiki.python.org.br/DocumentacaoPython  Senao mesmoa  melhor resposta pra esse problema especifico não vai te ajudar muito.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim

```
from tkinter import *


class Janela:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        pass


raiz = Tk()
Janela(raiz)
raiz.mainloop()
```